# Disable pointer-events only when dragging over an item

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have a container with dynamic content a user can interact with. It could be a YouTube video (iframe), amongst other things.

A user can drag and drop an image into this container and it'll replace the dynamic content with their image.

I'm aware that due to the dynamic content, drag events will behave erratically in the container, so I need to do `pointer-events: none`.

The HTML container has the following classes `ant-upload-drag` and `ant-upload-drag-hover`. The `ant-upload-drag-hover` class is only active when the image being dragged is on-top of the container.

I have CSS akin to the following where `ant-upload-drag-container` contains the dynamic content that I want unreachable by pointer-events:

```css
.ant-upload-drag-hover {
  .ant-upload-drag-container {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It causes the container to behave erratically with the `ant-upload-drag-hover` class added and removed from the container over and over and over.

Meanwhile, the following works:

```css
.ant-upload-drag {
  .ant-upload-drag-container {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

Essentially, as long as `.ant-upload-drag-container` is always `pointer-events: none;` things work as expected, but if the `pointer-events: none` is triggered dynamically on hover, then things don't go as planned.

The following video demonstrates visually:

https://share.getcloudapp.com/ApuRgQlZ

The first example shows what is desired (when pointer-events is always none). The second example shows the current state (when pointer-events is dynamically shifted to always none).

I know this isn't much to go off of, but I'm not sure if I fundamentally misunderstand `pointer-events: none`, or if some React rendering shenanigans are happening.

Presumably, the moment `ant-upload-drag-hover` class is added to the element, the `pointer-events: none` would trigger, but it seems like for some reason `pointer-events: none` is also triggered on the container or something else must be happening for the container to lose the hover state and remove the class.

Comment: I guess, that as soon as you add `pointer-events: none` you're no longer dragging over this container, because this container does no longer do pointer-events. So it then fires the *"I-am-no-longer-dragging-here"* event, which leads to `pointer-events: none` getting removed and Elvis is back in the building ... But it's just a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether `pointer-events: none` interferes with the drag-and-drop events but it would explain your bug.

I'd suggest that you instead put a layer on top of the container that catches these events instead.

Here an example with a button and the layer is toggles (by a class) every 3 seconds.

```js
// toggle class `ant-upload-drag-hover` every 3 seconds
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector(".ant-upload-drag").classList.toggle("ant-upload-drag-hover");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.ant-upload-drag-container {
  position: relative;
}

.ant-upload-drag-hover .ant-upload-drag-container::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* the rest is just for aesthetics: */
  content: " .ant-upload-drag-hover";
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

button {
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

button::before {
  content: "Click here: ";
}
```

```html
<div class="ant-upload-drag">
  <div class="ant-upload-drag-container">
    <button onclick="++this.textContent">0</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This took me down the right path. Thanks for the fresh perspective! Sometimes you tunnel vision down a path too much like I did with `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: Actually, this ended up not working... the psuedo element blocks all drags so my dragger can't detect drop events.

Comment: @David where did you add the overlay? It should be **inside** the element that listens to your drag events. Maybe you could update the question with a bare-minimum snippet that demonstrates the markup and the problem *(doesn't have to be a video inside it)*. Also, I just noticed an `<input type="file" />` in your `.ant-upload` element. What exactly is doing that during the drag/drop?

Comment: It is okay. I ended up solving my problem with some window event listeners. The code turned out to be quite small too. Thanks for leading me down the right path though.